# Is the Greek ζ related to the Chinese 子?

Tags: historical-linguistics, greek, chinese, phoenician

I wonder whether there is any connections between the two letters. After all, they are both similar to the Phoenician Sade letter, and the Phoenicians were the dominant culture of the Mediterranean Sea for 1000 years, so that the letter had had more than enough time to travel to China.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because lacks basic research.

Comment: I am downvoting this question because I think one could find countless meaningless similarities between completely unrelated glyphs. I am not voting to close as I think the question is in scope.

Comment: "the Phoenicians were the dominant culture of the Mediterranean Sea for 1000 years" [*citation needed*]

Answer (score 7):

[The Chinese character 子](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%AD%90#Chinese) appears to derive from a drawing of a baby with arms spread, which has a corresponding word [tsa](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Sino-Tibetan/tsa_%7E_za) in Sino-Tibetan, pronounced something like *tsəʔ* in Old Chinese. [Greek zeta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta) (Z), lower case ζ, derives from [Phoenician zayin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zayin), and was phonetically [z]: presumably it derives from a picture of some thing that started with *z*, but the "thing" etymology is unclear. The origin of the [letter Tsade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsade) (and other spellings) which was originally "emphatic" [sˁ] is also unclear, but its fate is that it gave rise to an ancient Greek letter San which disappeared from use. The first problem with your proposal is that it is believe that tsade is not related to zayin (but we can still consider it as a possibility, with the evidence being somewhat stacked against that idea).

The connection between Egyptian hieroglyphics and Semitic writing is also unclear, but it is credibly believed that Hieroglyphics at least influenced Semitic writing (e.g. ʕen looks like a picture of an eye). If we trace the Semitic letters back to the hieroglyphic shapes, any resemblance goes away, that is, the oldest shapes of the "child" character 子 looks very little like the "plant" shape thought to be the oldest form of *Tsade*, and also the "handcuff" picture thought to lead to *Zayin*. In other words, the comparison should not be between more modern shapes of letters, it should be between the oldest shapes. A comparison of Latin "w" and Hebrew "ש‎" would be completely misguided (the letters simply *look* similar), so your comparison correctly invokes sound-similarity as well as shape-similarity, but the *older* shapes are not sufficiently similar.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question despite all the downvotes. (I thought my question was innocent enough, but then I'm not a linguist myself.) Since one can't downvote comments, I'd like to use this opportunity to express my disagreement with the alleged misguidedness of using shape similarity only: If a shape is, say, easy to carve in stone, it may well have been adopted for a new use because of that, in principle at least. Isn't that true?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand completely, but let me offer that precisely because a cross, two parallels, a lozenge &c are the easiest forms to carve into a hard material, therefore one should expect these shapes to recur across cultures and ages without there being any causal relationships. When a highly complex, more specific shape is found in cultures that are held to be unrelated, that would be more difficult to explain. An analogous case are accidentally similar sounds for similar concepts across languages. One swallow does not a summer make.

Comment: "If we trace the Semitic letters back to the hieroglyphic shapes" Why don't you go ahead and do that. I don't believe there is a single piece of credible evidence

Comment: "In other words, the comparison should not be between more modern shapes of letters, it should be between the oldest shapes." This is incorrect. If you looked at Old English *waerd* and concluded that Modern English *waranty* is entirely unrelated to *guaranty*, in ignorance of French influence, you are going to have a bad time.

Comment: @vectory Look at the Proto-Sinaitic inscriptions.

Comment: well understood proto-sinaitic, wow, much decipher, no agenda, so monogenesis, very fiable, appeals to ignorance, I am le impressed, "plant" shape confirmed, looks plenty planty in plantasia land.

Comment: "The origin of [...] Tsade [...] is also unclear". The story I heard is it's related to צֶדֶק, meaning righteousness

Answer (score -4):

There is one "highly speculative" theory developed by Chris Button and shared reluctantly over multiple comments on Language Log (left as exercise to the reader) hinted at in one of the blog's guest posts (Old Chinese onsets and the calendrical signs, January 12, 2023):

> I'm a little reluctant to share any of my highly speculative correspondences between the ganzhi and the 22 symbols of the Phoenician alphabet because I don't want the correspondences to be used as grounds for criticizing my reconstructed onsets,

https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=57622

In this system, 子 is compared to Phoenician  *teth* (commonly identified as "wheel").

Compare Greek θ *theta* as in Θῖναι, Θῖνα, or Σῖναι viz. *China*, probably ultimately from 秦 *qin* OC [B-S] /*[dz]i[n]/ through Sanskrit *cīna*, ultimately uncertain https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%A3%E1%BF%96%CE%BD%CE%B1%CE%B9#Ancient_Greek

I do not recognize the ancient form in Button's table as what "appears to derive from a drawing of a baby with arms spread" (@user6726, above). Modern 子 might cover multiple uses, however.

---

In my own research, 了 MC *lewax* is obviously corresponding to Phoenician  *waw*, Egyptian dialects  /  and Arabic و‎ /w/ e.g.. ♀ as sign of *Venus* is derived from this, horizontal bar added later, easily confused with qoppa too.

The relation is less than clear and not supported by any theory. Let the evidence speak for itself. The clearest resemblance is born out by the following signs:

- Egyptian Hieroglyphic  /  *msj*

  > Representing a woman giving birth, in the posture that would typically be adopted by Egyptian women in such a scenario (crouching over birth bricks, though the bricks themselves are not depicted).

  Note the child's upper body protruding at the bottom. Variant of  *msj* "give birth", akin to  /  *ms* "child", in names "(child) of", abstract  *mswt* "birth".
- 育 MC *yuwk*

  > semantic  (“upside-down baby, being born”) + phonetic 肉 (OC **njuɡ*).

  > See 毓 (yù) for the earlier glyph.

  Note the sign's predecessor in Oracle Bone Script bears no resemblance to the Egyptian, above, but it looks superficially like Linear B  *ku*.
- 毓 MC *yuwk*

  > 每 + 㐬 – a woman giving birth. A woman 每 squatting on left, with child head down on right 㐬. **The top part of 㐬 is 子 inverted**, an abstracted body with a head at the bottom; compare 充. The lines (川) below head are amniotic fluid coming out.

  > A later alternative form is 育.

  (emphasis mine)

  The Oracle Bone Script of 㐬 ("a newborn baby, shown upside down.") retained in this sign is similar to 育. The resemblance of 母 MC *muwK* "woman" to anything is quite far fetched:

  > a woman with breasts with nipples kneeling or standing. In modern form turned on left side. Compare 女 (OC *naʔ, *nas, “woman”), which has developed similarly, but does not include dots for nipples and has lost one breast in the modern form.

  女 "woman" Is recalled in 生產 MC *sraeng(H) sraeng* "give birth" whereby

  - 產 "abbreviated phonetic 彥 (OC **ŋrans*) + semantic 生 (“to be born”).
  - 彥 "phonetic 厂 (OC *hŋaːnʔ, *hŋaːns) + semantic 彣 (“variegated; literary talent”)
  - 彣 is probably a woman with the amniotic fluid motive but without the baby

[https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%F0%93%81%92)
[https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/育](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%82%B2)
[https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/毓](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%AF%93)
[https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/㐬](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%90%AC)
[https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/母](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%AF%8D)
[https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/生產](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%94%9F%E7%94%A2)
[https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/產](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%94%A2)
[https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/彥](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%BD%A5)
[https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/彣](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%BD%A3)
[https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/流](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%B5%81)

This is not a thorough answer towards genetic (ha!) relations between Chinese and the Hieroglyphs which are commonly accepted as the basis of Phoenician and everything that follows, including Greek.

The clearest indication of some *relation* in the pedestrian sense is that 充 has legs, a common theme in Egyptian, yet an entirely hilarious idiosyncracy (the easiest way to claim coincidence would be to deny that those are legs).

The three lines of  are a late addition to  and may be interpreted as a ligature with , in Hieratic. It is never identified as a fluid. How  *ms* is identified as "three skins tied together" or "fox tails" may be hardly explainable (source?) but its use in spelling is not obviously related to the meaning of *ms* "birth" (Takács, Etymological Dictionary of Egyptian, vol. 3 (2007)). Notwithstanding  *foxtail millet* or *seed*.

The descending lines are visually similar to Egy.  "eye with flowing tears", 流眼淚 Mandarin *liú yǎnlèi* "to cry", cp. 流 MC *ljuw*. An eye pictograph also features in Sumero-Akkadian  U₃.TU *walādum* "to give birth, bear a child" viz.  IGI "eye".  ME "be",  TIL "live" not necessarily related. The prior for this comparison is German *Wehe* "labour pain": from PIE **way-* "woe, alas", cp. *weinen* "to cry", *wenig* "little" (子 itsy-bitsy), hence the focus on Egy. .

Further discussion of the evidence is out of scope and not in my power. This also means I cannot strictly rule out a relation to *zeta* though I will say the best match for Phoenician  if interpreted as rhebus of *zayin* "weapon" is probably Chinese 工, MC *kuwng* "tool".

---

NB: In Button's guest post, *waw* corresponds to a vessel (cf. 酉), *sade* to a Chinese axe (cf. 戌) and *zayin* ...

... *Zayin* would correspond to 巳, resembling in its Oracle Bone Script a form of 子, cf. Wiktionary: 巳

> Two different theories:

> - Pictogram (象形) of a snake (therefore, it should be similar to 巴). This theory is found in the Shuowen Jiezi;

> - **Pictogram (象形) of a fetus** (it can be seen in 包, 胞. In 包, the radical should represent the placenta. 胞 today means "cell").
>   The character is similar to 已, which cannot be found in the Shuowen Jiezi.

(emphasis mine)

[https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/巳](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%B7%B3)

Sobthe answer is yes, barely.

---

That said, *related* in the technical sense usually means a direct line of descent, hinging on an appropriate definition of descent. Chris Button does not make any claim of a historic scenario. The Sino-Tibetan language family remains debatable, but it is not related as such to Indo-European or Afro-Asiatic, notwithstanding Nostratic theory. Here be Dragons.

Comment: Even though I do not understand your answer completely, I think as recognition of your efforts I have to share my thought that I consider it extremely unlikely that humankind is around for 100,000 years and then 5,000 years ago several civilisations invent writing independently of each other.